# Micrometer tracing disabled error: required a bean of type 'io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, trace, micrometer, zipkin, micrometer-tracing

In my application I use the Tracer bean to get trace and span IDs:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeService {
    private final Tracer tracer;

    private TracingContext getTracingContext() {
        var context = Optional.ofNullable(tracer.currentTraceContext().context());
        return TracingContext.builder()
                .traceId(context.map(TraceContext::traceId).orElse("null"))
                .spanId(context.map(TraceContext::spanId).orElse("null"))
                .build();
    }

    public void doSomeJbob() {
      ...
      var context = getTracingContext();

      send_request_using<org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient>();

      ...
    }
}
```

The problem is when `management.tracing.enabled` property is set to false, the application doesn't start with Bean not found exception.
I created a workaround, I've created a @Bean in configuration:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass(Tracer.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "management.tracing", name = "enabled", havingValue = "false")
public Tracer defaultTracer() {
    return Tracer.NOOP;
}
```

The application starts, but then request called with `send_request_using<org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient>();` starts failing:
`Context does not have an entry for key [class io.micrometer.tracing.handler.TracingObservationHandler$TracingContext]`

What do I do wrong? Isn't tracing supposed to be disabled sometimes?

Comment: update micrometer dependency and put  Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation(); in main function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application mandates a `Tracer` bean to be created, but disabling tracing will result the absence of that bean.
Instead of making it mandatory, you can use [`ObjectProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html) instead:

```java
private final ObjectProvider<Tracer> tracerProvider;
```

Comment: @Mitsuder does this solution work for you? I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to define also NOOP `ObservationRegistry` bean like this:

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "management.tracing", name = "enabled", havingValue = "false")
@Configuration
public class NoopTracingConfig {

    @Bean
    Tracer tracer() {
        return Tracer.NOOP;
    }

    @Bean
    ObservationRegistry observationRegistry() {
        return ObservationRegistry.NOOP;
    }
}
```